# Removing text from a string file(java)

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove all the text between `<` and `>`. I am trying to get familiar with regular expressions so my code for this looks like:

```
line.replaceAll("<.*?>","");
```

I am replacing it line by line using a recursive method.

This is the whole method to clear things up. I am getting the same input and output.

```
    // recursively goes through the string and removes anything surrounded by "< >"
public static void removeTags(String line) {
    line.replaceAll("<.*?>","");
    cleanString = cleanString + line;
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        removeTags(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. `replaceAll` doesn't affect original string but creates new one.

Comment: Can you provide any example of input and output you getting ?

Comment: Oh okay. Pshemo has it. My problem is that I am essentially creating a new blank string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store your resulting string, so change this:

```
line.replaceAll("<.*?>","");
```

To

```
line = line.replaceAll("<.*?>","");
```

Comment: yupp. I had it right... i feel dumb now, for now actually storing the resulting string in the variable.